# What are these additional white lines on the cricket pitch?

Tags: rules, cricket

Some cricket pitches have an additional white line, perpendicular to both the bowling crease and popping crease, and joining both of them. One example is of the Eden Garden stadium pitch (2016)

[video source](https://youtu.be/MWffCEif940?t=1m6s)

[image: a screenshot of a cricket match with some lines circled in red]

I have highlighted the line in question in a pink box. There are three more lines, a total of two on each side of the pitch. I checked [Law 7 - The Creases](https://www.lords.org/mcc/laws-of-cricket/laws/law-7-the-creases/) and [Law 6 - the Pitch](https://www.lords.org/mcc/laws-of-cricket/laws/law-6-the-pitch/), and could not find any reference to these lines.

What are they? Are they not standard lines i.e. why are they not on every pitch? What is their purpose?

Comment: Shorthand for *"spelling/grammar/syntax"*. It means fewer characters in the edit summary to get past, for what is usually a small component of the edit.

Answer (score 4):

The line which you have highlighted in the image is the wide marking. They provide the limits within which bowlers have to bowl and assist umpires in adjudging if a delivery can be called "wide".

Sources:
1) http://premier.cricketvictoria.com.au/files/3/files/premier-match-rules/Crease%20Markings%20Diagram%20and%20Wide%20Ball%20Interpretation%20White%20Ball%20Cricket%20Guidance.pdf

2) http://cricket.rushisbiz.com/cricket-pitch-and-ball-details/

Comment: Interesting, thanks for your answer! Any idea why these rules are not given in the laws? And why do many pitches _not_ display the wide lines?

Comment: They're only used in ODI (One-Day International) and Twenty-20 cricket, so they won't be marked for a multi-day game. They're not in the laws because they're defined as regulations for a specific form or forms of cricket, while the items in the Laws are for all forms of cricket.

Comment: As a canonical source, I'd suggest the [T20I Playing Conditions, Appendix C, Section 1](https://pulse-static-files.s3.amazonaws.com/ICC/document/2017/10/05/827e3bdd-6306-404e-8c62-47ae2f0ea223/ICC-Men-s-T20I-Playing-Conditions-2017-Code-FINAL-051017.pdf). (The diagram is identical in the ODI playing conditions).